# AutoMapper Setting properties Null in Nested List

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using Automapper in a .Net Core 3 application and I have a very simple scenario and I don't realize what I'm doing wrong.

The destination object is not keeping the values in the unused fields.

Follow below the code that I'm using....

1. Source Class

   ```
   public class Origin
   {

       public long key { get; set; }
       public List<OriginItem> items { get; set; } = new List<OriginItem>();

   } //class

   public class OriginItem 
   {
       public string itemFieldA { get; set; }
       public string itemFieldB { get; set; }
   } //class
   ```
2. Destination Class

   ```
   public class Destination
   {

       public long key { get; set; }
       public List<DestinationItem> items { get; set; } = new List<DestinationItem>();

   } //class

   public class DestinationItem 
   {
       public string itemFieldA { get; set; }
       public string itemFieldB { get; set; }
       public string itemFieldC { get; set; }  //I want to preserve this information      
       public string itemFieldD { get; set; }  //I want to preserve this information
   } //class
   ```

My Automapper profiles for this classes are:

```
public class ProfileAutoMapping : Profile
{

    public ProfileAutoMapping ()
    {
        CreateMap<Origin, Destination>();
    } //constructor

} //class

public class ItemAutoMapping : Profile
{

    public ItemAutoMapping ()
    {
        CreateMap<OriginItem, DestinationItem>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.itemFieldC, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
          .ForMember(dest => dest.itemFieldD, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
    } //constructor

} //class
```

I'm using the map in the following action

```
    public IActionResult action(Origin origin)
    {

        Destination destination = _repository.GetById(origin.key);

        if (destination!= null)
        {
            _mapper.Map(origin, destination);

            //Updating 
            _repository.Update(destination);

        } //if

        return View();

    } //action
```

**The problem: The destinaton object, after apply the Map is not keeping the original values in unused fields**

Origin object before mapping (JSON format just for understanding):

```
  "origin" : { 
    "key": "1", 
     "items" : [
       {"itemFieldA": "X",
        "itemFieldB": "Y" 
       }]
   }

  "destination" : { 
    "key": "1", 
     "items" : [
       {"itemFieldA": "A",
        "itemFieldB": "B", 
        "itemFieldC": "C", 
        "itemFieldD": "D", 
       }]
   }
```

After apply Map()

```
  "destination" : { 
    "key": "1", 
     "items" : [
       {"itemFieldA": "X",
        "itemFieldB": "Y", 
        "itemFieldC": null, //<============= **ERROR! I want to maintain the original value**
        "itemFieldD": null //<============= **ERROR! I want to maintain the original value**
       }]
   }
```

Comment: It seems like you want to use `.ForMember(dest => dest.items, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())` for the `Origin` -> `Destination` mapping so it doesn't build a new list of (new) `Destination` objects.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Progman... but what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using the `.ForMember()` statement I wrote? What is the result you get? When you run your application in debug mode and give the list and debug ID, does the list stays the same or is a new list being generated? And is `_repository.GetById()` returning a `Destination` object with filled `DestinationItem` objects (which have the `itemFieldC` and `itemFieldD` properties set)?

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: @Progman: I changed for "CreateMap<origin, destination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.items, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());" but still not working..

Comment: @JulioSchurt Please check https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection for working on collections with automapper as mentioned by Lucian Bargaoanu and http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html